# Implement Trait on Arc<T>

Tags: rust

How do you implement a trait like `Hash` on `Arc<T>`, where `T` is a custom-defined type?

I am trying to do this because I have defined a type `T`, but Rust complains that you can't define new traits on `Arc<....>` of any kind.

Comment: You can't, because `Arc<T>` is already `Hash` when `T: Hash`. You could have conflicting implementations. On the flip side, if you `impl Hash for T` then you're done.

Comment: Even if your type isn't `Hash` (and there is no conflict) you still can't, because `Arc` is a foreign type and `Hash` is a foreign trait.